# how to build com.netflix.client.http.httpresponse object

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, httpresponse, spock, netflix

I am writing `unit test` cases, using `mocking` concept, I am `mocking RestClient class` 
original code:

```
final HttpResponse response = restClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(request);
```

Test class mock code in `Spock`:

```
restClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(_ as HttpRequest) >> httpResponse
```

here I have to build and set `httpResponse`. How to build HttpResponse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [HttpResponse](https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon/blob/master/ribbon-httpclient/src/main/java/com/netflix/client/http/HttpResponse.java) is an interface and you can't really build or create instance of it.what you can able to do is probably create instance of class that implements this interface. for eg: [HttpClientResponse](https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon/blob/master/ribbon-httpclient/src/main/java/com/netflix/niws/client/http/HttpClientResponse.java)

and you can build and set `httpResponse`
 anything you like as below,

```
ClientResponse clientResponse = Mock(ClientResponse)
MultivaluedMapImpl sampleHeaders = new MultivaluedMapImpl()
sampleHeaders.add("name", "test")
clientResponse.getHeaders() >> sampleHeaders
HttpResponse httpResponse = new HttpClientResponse(clientResponse,null,null)

restClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(_ as HttpRequest) >> httpResponse
```

on a side note ,to mock ClientResponse  you need the [objenesis](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.objenesis/objenesis) in your classpath.